# WinPhone app event to react on app process termination

Tags: windows-phone, termination, application-lifecycle, tombstoning

When we deactivate a WP app, it can be tombstoned and terminated later by the OS. I need to save some unsaved app data to a persistent storage when the process is terminated, but not before this. Obviously, the Deactivated event cannot be used for this purpose as it is raised immediately when an app is moved to the background; the Close event is also not the event we need as it si not raised when the app process is terminated by the OS. Is there a special Windows Phone app event for that, something like Application_Terminated?

Comment: It's recommended that your app saves its important data in incremental way. Another risky way is using `PhoneApplicationService`'s `State` : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817009%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the operating system only tombstones your app when it is under severe resource pressure. At the time it is not practical to wake up the app and run app code because it might risk whatever is currently in the foreground. This limitation exists on all modern mobile operating systems (Android, IOS included). This is just the cost of operating in a battery/resource friendly environment.

Having said that, it sounds like your backing store does not disambiguate between data the user "saved" and data that is just being cached until the user can finish the transaction. It would be useful to build the idea in. Think of it the way some of the smarter web sites on the internet now work. You can navigate away while you were in the middle of entering data and when you come back the site presents you with the partially filled form. The site understands that you weren't "done" but it respects the fact that you had provided some of the information you'd need to get "done".

What I'm saying here is that the problem is easily fixed by understanding and accommodating the way your users are likely to use the app. Thinking of your app like a web site (at least in this context) helps out things into perspective. Sorry about the longish answer. I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such event. You should save your state on Deactivated so that if the application is removed from memory (tombstoned) you can set yourself up again upon reactivation. If your problem is figuring out whether or not you need to restore state on Activated, check out the ActivatedEventArgs.IsApplicationInstancePreserved flag (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.activatedeventargs.isapplicationinstancepreserved(v=vs.105).aspx). This flag tells you whether your app was tombstoned. If it wasn't, you can throw away the old state or overwrite it the next time you are deactivated.

Comment: I do so right now, and do use IsApplicationInstancePreserved. I would prefer not to save the current unsaved data entered by the user in the Deactivated event as in this case we lose the OK/Cancel functionality we need when our app is deactivated.